# What is usually listed as evidence that RPGs are inherently a 2+ person activity?

Tags: social, solo

I often see some people in the table top RPG claim that RPGs are inherently social. As such, the claim is used to invalidate the existence of solitaire rpg'ing, computer RPGs as "real rpgs", etc.

I have been unable to find the evidence that backs this claim that RPGs must exclusively be social, and often the evidence presented tends to beg the question. For example, "RPGs are social because you can't have a shared imagined space if you play by yourself." This begs the question of why you need a shared imagined space in the first place, since a shared imagined space is already implied by the 2+ person claim.

So, the claim is that RPG'ing MUST happen with other people involved. What is usually listed as evidence directly backing this claim? Failing that, what are the usual reasoned arguments behind this, and the evidence listed as backing those arguments?

For example, a reasoned argument with some evidence behind it would not be a definition of roleplaying games themselves, but an official dictionary definition of its components that specifies those components require more than one person be engaged in them would be fine.

Comment: I've cleared the extended discussion about terms on this question.

Comment: @user15299 The problem is that the definition of "RPG" is merely conventional, meaning that it means only what people say it means as a matter of convention and general agreement. There's no evidence you can find that's separate from people's opinions on what the word "should" mean and include. There might be reasoned arguments, but they can't be logical and based on external evidence, they would necessarily be persuasion-based arguments based on sense and feeling.

Comment: @user15299 Welcome to StackExchange RPG. We are a community about specific questions for specific problem. Your question was closed because answers would primarily be opinion-based. The comments were deleted because comments are for clarification or improving a question and it degenerated into a discussion (almost chat-like). Look at [what types of question we try to avoid](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Let me see if I can clarify. I'm not really looking for discussion. What I'm looking for is perhaps best described as a listing of evidence (if there is any), or at least a list of common reasoned arguments that are supported by evidence of some sort. Those things should at least be trying support the claim that RPGing must involve other people without being tautological in this manner: "RPGing must involve other people because a shared imagined space has to exist" or "RPGing must involve other people because you can't have a social contract without other people". Hope that helps!

Comment: Thinking about it, however, I would add that it would be better if the definition was not about roleplaying games themselves, but the act of taking on a role, or the definition of a game.

Comment: Who makes this claim? Why are you asking? What do you intend to get out of this question? Why do you care what the initial unidentified "someones" or indeed any citations in an answer to this question say?

Comment: Because I want to know what the usual justifications are for this position, especially if they are actual evidence, or arguments backed by some evidence. Should the answers to your questions be part of my question? Otherwise, why are you asking?

Comment: This is sounding more and more like a request to compile a list of stuff, which is a type of question that works poorly enough in the Stack Exchange system that they're deemed automatically off-topic as a category. I don't see a way to make this not a list question, either.

Comment: Not to keep harping on it, but I found a post that asks whether there is a list of non-ogl monsters. Would asking if there is a list of what I'm asking for pass the litmus test?  http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/2776/is-there-a-list-of-non-ogl-monsters

Comment: I don't think this is a particularly good or useful question, and I *really* doubt we'll get any good answers to it, but at least the query for specific evidence that *actually gets used* is, in theory, answerable. I still suspect that the answers won't have it (I don't think that exists in the first place), which will lead to a lot of downvoted answers and suggest that no, this wasn't a good question in the first place, but since it's now, in theory, an answerable question, I've left a vote to reopen, if only to giver 15299 a chance.

Comment: The frame-challenge in AceCalhoon's answer is what redeems this for me enough to vote to reopen.

Comment: So what about this question isn't answered by http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/792/looking-for-solo-one-person-rpgs-do-they-exist?rq=1 - there *are* solo RPGs. You're asking us to refute "something unclear someone said somewhere on the internet."

Comment: I will note that since this may end up on meta, Christianity.SE had to clamp down on "I hear someone says" questions in favor of specific denomination doctrinal statements, because "rebutting something someone said" (often uncited) is totally pointless and you have to answer them all with @AceCalhoon's answer below.

Comment: This question feels like a request that we use Google to find evidence that confirms a straw man the questioner has positioned in order to invalidate the notion that roleplaying games require more than one person.

Comment: The question isn't "do solo rpg exist", the question is obviously about the  "Lumpley Principle" and what justifications exist for it. People have a tendency to  parrot some version of it they likely heard second hand. The answers to this question might be in Vince Baker's original posts linked from this wiki:  http://big-model.info/wiki/Lumpley_Principle

In a fraction of the time the mob took to tear OP a new anus, I was able to find something potentially useful for a person asking for help. I deserve a gazillion points.

Comment: By the way, OP, I suggest you remove any references to solo or computer rpgs. Those are tangential and they are causing confusion in some readers.

Comment: Even with that, I'm not really interested in our Q&A being a proxy for some Internet argument about definitions. If the only problem this solves is "how to fight more on the Internet" it should be taken to a forum.

Comment: This has 48 deleted comments. I'm going to lock this for a while. If people want to continue this argument, take it to meta.

Comment: I would suggest that the question should really be "Are RPGs defined as 2+ player games, and not solo games?" And the correct answer is "No. See OED, meaning of the words used, and the existence of many solitaire RPGs both on computer and in print since at least the 1970s. There are no usual arguments for this. Those people should make up a new term such as 'Social RPG'."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No one can actually point you to evidence, or reasoned argument for this, because it doesn't actually exist.  The argument is made on assumptions, assertions, and shifting goalposts, often with a fair amount of the "No True Scotsman" argument thrown in.

But!  What might be more useful is to go over some of the reasons people think this way, so that you can at least disambiguate what's going on when that argument presents itself.

**Games where fiction affects play vs. not**

First, it's important to note there is a key difference in defining something as an "RPG" because it:

- Uses persistent character advancement mechanics
- Has a character story where you can make some branching choices
- Has character customization
- Aims to achieve identification with the character
- [Has a way for players' imaginations to directly affect the outcomes of play](http://bankuei.wordpress.com/2010/07/31/rpgs-and-definitions/)

The last one is pretty much the one thing tabletop RPGs have completely different than any other kind of game in existence, and as such, represents a unique medium of play.  This makes it useful to recognize it is different than others for both design and experience, but that doesn't mean other types of games are bad or lesser games.

A lot of people are using this definition when they say other games "aren't real RPGs" even though they may not be able to articulate it as such.

**What this means for Solo Games**

Well, when you use that definition, a lot of solo games do not count - boardgames, "Choose Your Own Adventures", videogames, and even the solo random generated dungeon crawl typically doesn't count because there's no real rules to help a player to navigate which/how fictional events/choices should apply beyond the hard mechanical rules.

A core idea to multiplayer tabletop RPGs is this idea of "how does the group decide how the fiction influence play outcomes?" which is pretty much the idea of the [Lumpley-Care Principle](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgamedesigner/13507/emily-care-boss) by Vincent Baker & Emily Care Boss.  In multiplayer, it's really about figuring out who can say what and have authority to make it "real" as far as the game outcomes are concerned.

For solo play, on the other hand, there's just you.  There has to be compelling procedures or concepts as a core part of play to make it more interesting than either:

"I win because I want to win, therefore I win." or,

"I don't win yet, until I want to win, then I win because I want to win."

(or lose because you want to lose, etc.)

In other words, there needs to be more creative pressure to make solo play something other than just the equivalent of daydreaming.

A few years back, there was a push for solo games by several designers and I know some came out of it, though the only one which I'm familiar with is [Ben Lehman's Beloved](http://www.tao-games.com/beloved/).  This game focuses on making an intense premise set up to force you to wrestle your own brain, intensely, as the point of play.  Until I had seen this game, I also fell into the camp of "I haven't seen it, therefore it can't be done".

**All in All**

The arguments behind "you cannot have a solo rpg" boil down to either poor communication about what the game medium is you're talking about, or, simply the fact that most people haven't seen a 1 player tabletop rpg and just assume it is impossible.

Comment: Best answer so far.

Answer (score 21):

This is ultimately a word game. The trouble you will always run into is that no one is "in charge" of the phrase "Role Playing Game," and therefore people can define it however they want.

The people you are talking to define a Role Playing Game something like this:

- Governed by rules.
- Has roleplaying.
- Involves interaction between multiple players.

By this definition, solo RPGs fundamentally can't exist. You can create something that's solo, a game, and involves roleplaying, but it's not a Role Playing Game, because it doesn't fit the definition.

Sound arbitrary? It is! Welcome to language. There's nothing to stop someone from saying that an RPG requires social interaction, just as there's nothing stopping someone from saying that an RPG requires advancement, or dice, or anything else.

At the end of the day, your best bet is to not dwell too long on the words people use. Someone on the Internet saying that a Solo RPG isn't an RPG doesn't change the fact that the thing you're playing is fun.

*[[image]
Source](http://xkcd.com/386/)*

**Postscript: Why this is a hard question**

Ultimately the hard part of this problem is that the answer varies depending on who we're talking about. It's not enough to just say "some people don't consider solo RPGs to be RPGs." We need to know *which people*, *which RPGs*, and *why they exclude them*.

Consider the video game *Diablo*. This site says it's not an RPG, because it's a computer game. But a BioWare fan-site may say that it's not an RPG because it doesn't have dialog-trees. Both of us are saying that *Diablo* isn't an RPG, but for entirely different reasons. We would each present entirely different evidence to support our definitions, and each side's evidence would be entirely meaningless to the other.

Meanwhile, *Diablo* will still happily market itself as an RPG.

With that said, there are two primary ways that a definition comes about:

- *Kinship* -- How alike is this RPG to others the community has seen before? Does the community feel the differences between this new thing and the original archetypes are substantial, or mostly superficial?
- *Purpose* -- Can the new thing replace an old RPG? Or is it an entirely new experience? Do I use it at the same times and places? With the same sorts of people? To trigger the same emotions?

Note that both of these are pretty vague. They may, or may not, exclude solo-play RPGs. The history of the speaker and the purpose of the word use will determine whether or not solo-play RPGs fit.

**Postscript 2: What evidence looks like**

For the sake of completeness, here are two examples of cases where solo RPGs should be excluded from the term "role playing game." These aren't meant as proof that solo RPGs should be banned from the term *for everyone, always*. Just cases where it is likely that they should be excluded for a particular conversation.

- *"I'm looking for something new to do with my Saturday nights. Can someone recommend an RPG?"*

  If I ask this, and you recommend a solo RPG, I might perhaps respond that they're not really an RPG [for the purposes of this discussion].

  You can point to any definition you like, but in this case my purpose in asking is clearly to find something to do with my friends. A solo RPG doesn't satisfy the needs of the word in this context, and would therefore be excluded.

  To use an example from your question, for the purposes of this example, "a shared imagined space" is crucial because I'm looking for something that brings me and other people together.
- *"I just played this neat thing called D&D for the first time! The hacking, the slashing, the DM's clever plots, my friends talking in funny voices! Let's talk about games like that!"*

  In this case, it is likely that a solo RPG is simply too far removed from the type of experiences the person is talking about. It is fair for them to say that it doesn't sound anything like the kind of experience they wanted to talk about.

Again, the *context* of the claim determines what evidence for or against it matters. Give us a concrete example of who's asking, and we can tell you more. But in general, the answer is vague and unsatisfying.

Comment: You got the words out of my mouth. I was typing something like this! +1!

Comment: It's not a question of someone being wrong on the internet. It's a question of wanting to find out if there is actually a strong case for the claim. If there is, then I think it might implications for the activity we call solo rpging and how we think about it or even approach it. :)

Comment: @user15299 A strong case for what? By that definition of "roleplaying game", a solo RPG can't exist. The definition says so quite explicitly. If you use a different definition of RPG, then a solo one can exist.

Comment: Exactly what I'm wanting to find out, if at all possible. If there is a strong case based on evidence to exclude what I call solo rpging from the definition of rpging, then I think it's worth hearing it. How you classify something might have implications to how you approach it. I've never seen even a weak case for the claim that you need other people, though, so I'm wondering if there is anything that I'm missing.

Comment: @user15299 There is no single, official definition of the phrase "Role Playing Game." Therefore there can be no "evidence" of the type you are looking for (one way or the other).

Comment: Maybe it's not stated correctly. How about: I'm looking for the evidence backing any arguments for this claim.

Comment: @acecalhoon did you check the OED?

Comment: This answer could be improved if you cited your definition. Such as http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/role-playing-game

Comment: @GmNoob I'm not quite following what you mean here. I would hardly consider the OED to be experts on RPGs, nor is my personal definition terribly important.

Comment: You should ask about whatever problem you're really trying to solve instead of this "prove to me" question - this answer is really the only legit one the way it currently stands.

Comment: @acecalhoon true, but it is normally considered an expert on the english language.

Comment: @GMNoob The problem is that the phrase as we understand it is too specialized for OED to have much chance at it. For example, their definition breaks down for the sentence "In recent years, Call of Duty has begun to add RPG elements..." The word is simply too fractured at this time.

Comment: I feel like this answer redeems the question, if only by challenging its frame so skillfully.

Comment: This answer is off topic. The question isn't "do solo role playing games exist?" The question is really, "what are the premises behind 'claim X'?", where X is the Lumpley Principle.

Comment: @Keoma The question is *not* about the Lumpley Principle, the Lumpley Principle is one example of the phenomenon the question asks about. If the question was about the Lumpley Principle specifically, it would be a much better question with a much more precise answer. Likewise, this answer isn't about whether solo RPGs exist, but about why someone might say they do not... Which is what the question asks for.

Comment: The Lumpley Principle is essentially a name coined for that notion.  Your answer did not list any premises for the conclusion that role playing games must, by their very nature, be played in a group. The operative word here is "for" not "against".  Your answer illustrated arguments against solo ppgs in situations where someone is clearly asking for something involving other people; that is tangential at best.

Comment: @Keoma My answer, from the first paragraph to the last, lists one fundamental reason why role playing games must, by their very nature, be played in a group: Because "played in a group" is part of the definition (some people) use for the phrase "Role Playing Game." As to *why* they define it that way, Vincent Baker (Lumpley) likely had specific reasons for defining it that way. Those reasons are not necessarily the ones used by Adam Dray in his comment to "Do solo RPGs exist?", or others.

Comment: That answer sounds exactly like the kind of tautological answer the OP said he wasn't looking for. Who holds the belief is irrelevant. What's relevant is the non-tautological reasoning behind it which OP wants to know about.

Comment: @Keoma Who holds the belief is the easiest access to precisely what the belief is. We can look at Lumpley's writing to find out why *he* excludes solo RPGs (apparently mostly because he doesn't think they'd be fun without an external observer).

Comment: @Keoma As to my arguments, they are not Tautological (self proving). Tautological would be "people define RPGs this way because people define RPGs this way." My statement is "Some people define RPGs this way because [reason varies too wildly to state succinctly, please clarify question]."

Comment: Saying that people believe roleplaying games are X way because they define it as being X way is tautological.

I'm not sure what Adam Dray has to do with OP, but it is clear from the question that OP is talking about people who only offer reasoning that repeats the disputed claim. You're assuming that OP already knew about Vince Baker and that Vince Baker's reasoning is tautological-- two things which could be false.

A more useful approach would have been to ask if OP knew about the origin of that claim and checked it out, or to ask the people in question to elaborate beyond their answer.

Comment: @Keoma Adam Dray is a commentor on [this thread](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/792/looking-for-solo-one-person-rpgs-do-they-exist?rq=1) who expresses the viewpoint the OP was asking about. And while I thank you for some interesting reading regarding Lumpley's principle, we seem to be at the point of talking past each other. I feel my answer stands as it is for this question as expressed. If you are interested in a more specific form of the question, feel free to ask a new one.